# How to make a parse function receiving string as argument regarding lex and yacc?

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I want to write a parser that provides API like `const char *convertA2B(const char *input)`. It looks like:

1. lex_and_yacc(input) -> myADT
2. myADT.intepret() -> ouptut

In yacc, there's `int yyparse(void)`, it seems relying the `yyin` varaible.
Is there any way I can directly parse a string, without these magical global variables?

Answer (score 0):

`yyparse` doesn't use `yyin` directly, it only calls `yylex` to get the tokens. Which input the tokens are generated from is entirely up to the lexer.

A lex- or flex-generated lexer will read from `yyin` by default, but you can use [yy_scan_string](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#index-yy_005fscan_005fstring) to read from a string instead.